# Avoid Visual Studio autoformatting code in specific region

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, editorconfig

When using an .editorconfig to configure formatting and enabling automatic formatting (or running `dotnet format`, is there any way to suppress the formatting for a specific region/block of code?

E.g. I have one file with 1000 constants defined which are aligned in neat columns. For such exceptions I want to use something like

```cs
class Example
{
#preserve-format
   // A block I want automatic formatting to just ignore
   const int A      = 123;
   const int Longer = 234;
   const int ...
   ...
#end-preserve-format

   // Formatter works normally here
   public void Foo() 
   { 
   } 
}
```

Is there anything that will accomplish this?

Comment: I doubt there is any. You may use your VCS and re-roll all the formattings there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use #pragma

```
class Example
{
#pragma warning disable format
   // A block I want automatic formatting to just ignore
   const int A      = 123;
   const int Longer = 234;
   const int ...
   ...
#pragma warning restore format

   // Formatter works normally here
   public void Foo() 
   { 
   } 
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about `format` before, neat! I'll leave my answer as an alternative, anyway.

Comment: Yeah, it is cool :D

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `#pragma` you could split the class into two parts and apply a different formatting rule for the file that contains the neatly formatted constants, e.g.:

Example class Part 1: *Example.Part1.cs*

```cs
partial class Example
{
   // A block I want automatic formatting to just ignore
   const int A      = 123;
   const int Longer = 234;
   // ...
}
```

Then add the rest of the class into Part 2: *Example.Part2.cs*

```cs
partial class Example
{
   // Formatter works normally here
   public void Foo() 
   { 
   }
}
```

In your *.editorconfig* you can then override the formatting rules for the *Example.Part1.cs* file:

```
[*/**Example.Part1.cs]
csharp_space_around_declaration_statements = ignore
```